# Ansible can't find downloaded file

Tags: ansible

I'm pretty new to Ansible and trying to automate the job of installing a TeamSpeak 3 server. Sadly I'm encountering some errors:

- If I try to run this it with the `ansible-playbook` command it asks for a sudo password even tho I explicitly stated the `become_pass` in the inventory
- If I retry it by using the `--ask-become-pass` parameter it runs the first two steps and states that it can't find the downloaded file, when connecting to the server however I can assure that it exists

Is this a permission error? Or can't I access the home directory because I didn't store the ssh key yet?

This is the playbook (at the moment):

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: Adding TeamSpeak User
      user:
        name: ts3

    - name: Download TeamSpeak
      get_url:
        url: https://files.teamspeak-services.com/releases/server/3.9.1/teamspeak3-server_linux_amd64-3.9.1.tar.bz2
        dest: /home/ts3/

    - name: Extract downloaded folder
      unarchive:
        src: /home/ts3/teamspeak3-server_linux_amd64-3.9.1.tar.bz2
        dest: /home/ts3
```

Comment: If SSH key is not stored, how are you running the playbook? By mentioning the key to the host as a parameter?

Comment: can you show the output? 
hints: 
1. use `remote_src: yes` in `unarchive`
2. use only one task `unarchive` with URL as a `src`

Comment: @PrakashKrishna SSH key for the newly created user isn't stored. For the executing user it of cause is.

Comment: @itiic Thank you for your help, it works now. Output was something like 'permission error', sorry that I didn't add this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### remote_src is missing

```
- name: Unarchive a file that is already on the remote machine
  unarchive:
    src: /tmp/foo.zip
    dest: /usr/local/bin
    remote_src: yes
```

#### You can combine both your tasks as single task, by replacing src with the URL as shown below

```
- name: Unarchive a file that needs to be downloaded (added in 2.0)
  unarchive:
    src: https://example.com/example.zip
    dest: /usr/local/bin
    remote_src: yes
```

Comment: To be honest I thought that the remote_src parameter implies an external source from the ansible clients view, but it is from the ansible servers view.

Comment: No, that's not me.